# apache airflow scheduler not working properly

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've created some `DAG`s, and I tried to put it on scheduler. I want to run all the tasks in the DAG after exact 24 hours.
I tried to do something like this.

```
DEFAULT_ARGS        = {
'owner'           : 'mubin',
'depends_on_past' : False,
'start_date'      : datetime(2017, 4, 24, 14, 30),
'retries'         : 5,
'retry_delay'     : timedetla(1),
}
SCHEDULE_INTERVAL      = timedelta(minutes=1440)
# SCHEDULE_INTERVAL    = timedelta(hours=24)
# SCHEDULE_INTERVAL    = timedelta(days=1)
dag = DAG('StandardizeDataDag',
    default_args       = DEFAULT_ARGS,
    schedule_interval  = SCHEDULE_INTERVAL
)
```

I tried to put different intervals, but not any working. However if I try to reset db `airflow resetdb -y` and then run `airflow initdb`, it works for once. then after that, scheduler isn't able to run it.
**airflow version: v1.8.0**

PS. `airflow scheduler` is executed via `root`

can anybody point me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you activate the task in the UI? The scheduler will not pick tasks that are not turned on in the list of DAGs. Also, `timedelta(minutes=1440)` is 24 hours which means you are running it every day at midnight. This is the value by default, you don't need to pass the `schedule_interval` in that case.

Comment: @HugoSousa, I did turn that on from GUI and I also tried to `unpause` this.

Comment: what if I want to run it at 3:00 am instead of 12? then in that case, I need to put start time, right? Is there any way/settings that I can use to run the program every day @ 3:00 am? can you suggest me settings and `DAG` properties for that?

Comment: If you want to run it at 3am you can define the `schedule_interval` as `'0 3 * * *'`. By default your DAG will run daily at 00:00. When you change your DAG `schedule_interval` your are changing based on that time.

Comment: What I have done is,  set schedule interval to `timedelta (hours=24)` and executed it at 3 am, now it has base time set to 3 am and interval is 24 hours, should it work fine now?

Comment: No, it will run at midnight... it doesn't take into account the time you executed it! It has a base time by default and that base time is midnight. Everything you do in terms of scheduling thing of it as having midnight as base time. So if you want to run it at 3am just do what I said in the previous comment.

Comment: What if my base time is 3 am?

Comment: You are not understanding... the way Airflow works is: it uses midnight as base time! All math you have to do is having midnight as base time. So, if you want to run at 3am, you need to do midnight + 3 hours, that's why `timedelta(hours=3)` which means add 3 hours to midnight!

Comment: So what's the solution after long discussion in the comments section ? Asking bcoz there is no answer to the question here!